# android change default item in bottom bar

Tags: android, material-design, bottomnavigationview, bottombar

I use bottom bar in my application .but I want to change default item(tab) in bottom bar.I do not use any external library.just how I can set my favorite tab when application runs.

**My codes:**

```
BottomNavigationView bottomNavigationView = (BottomNavigationView) findViewById(R.id.navigation);
bottomNavigationView.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener(new BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
        Fragment selectedFragment = null;
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.action_home:
                selectedFragment = Fragment1.newInstance();
                break;
            case R.id.action_product:
                selectedFragment = Fragment2.newInstance();
                break;
            case R.id.action_order:
                selectedFragment = Fragment3.newInstance();
                break;
            case R.id.action_contact:
                selectedFragment = Fragment4.newInstance();
                break;
        }

        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        FragmentTransaction transaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
        transaction.replace(R.id.scrollView, selectedFragment);
        transaction.commit();
        return true;
    }

});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work (I use it with api 19+)

```
bottomNavigationView.getMenu().getItem(index).setChecked(true);
```

Answer (score 2):

```
bottomNavigationView.setSelectedItemId(R.id.action_home);
```

This will work

Comment: Is the bottom navigation bar a external library?

Comment: Which one do you want to set as default?

Comment: my app direction is right to left and I set support ltr false in manifest.now the last item from right(and the first item from left) is active and I want change it to first item from right.

Comment: Which fragment do you want to set as the selected fragment?

Comment: the fragment I want to set default is fragment 1

Comment: it works for api 25 and higher .how I can use for lower api?

Answer (score 1):

```
    for (int i = 0, size = menu.size(); i < size; i++) {
        MenuItem item = menu.getItem(i);
        item.setChecked(item.getItemId() == 0);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want a specific item to be opened when the app is started. Just try this code:

```
bottomNavigationView.setSelectedItemId(R.id.your_id);
```

**But it is for API 25 and higher only.**

Comment: how can I use for lower api?